# MASM32 fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals

Tags: assembly, masm32, sasm

I installed SimpleASM and MASM32 to learn assembly. I am now reading a book and try the code written in it.

```
; AddTwo.asm - adds two 32-bit integers
; Chapter 3 example

.386
.model flat,stdcall
.stack 4096
ExitProcess PROTO, dwExitCode: DWORD

.code
main PROC
mov eax, 5     ; move 5 to the eax register
add eax,6     ; add 6 to the eax register

INVOKE    ExitProcess,0
main ENDP
END main
```

but when i try to build the code, this is it what the console says

```
[17:56:02] Warning! Errors have occurred in the build:
program.o : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _ExitProcess@4
C:\Users\De\AppData\Local\Temp\SASM\SASMprog.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
```

edit:

while i extract the masm32. in the cmd part it says

```
"inc2l.exe - Ordinal Not Found"
"The ordinal 203 could not be located in the dynamic link library
WINSPOOL.DRV."
```

i just ignore it.. and it keeps showing.. i just pressing enter until the assembly is installed

Comment: You forgot to link with kernel32?

Comment: while i extract the masm32. in the cmd part it says 
    "inc2l.exe - Ordinal Not Found"

    "The ordinal 203 could not be located in the dynamic link library
    WINSPOOL.DRV."

i just ignore it.. and it keeps showing.. i just pressing enter until the assembly is installed

Comment: If you are getting that WINSPOOL error I suggest you reinstall MASM32 with your Anti Virus software turned off. Then turn on the Av sofwtare when complete.

Comment: oh.. i see.. i don't have any AV.. maybe the windows defender? my computer also has virus... maybe virus affects it?? the first time i installed masm32.. it says nothing... but i deleted it and reinstall it.. and now it says inc2l.exe - ordinal not found... ill try to reinstall it now..

Comment: i already fixed the WINSPOOL error but still the LNK2001 error is happening.

Comment: Jester gave you a hint in his first comment.

Comment: how to link with kernel32?